# Android Auto Backup: App loses all broadcast receivers after backup run

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-backup-service

I'm using Android Auto Backup for Apps on Android 7.1.1. My app has a user setting to enable or disable full backup. I implemented this by extending the `BackupAgent` class and overriding `onFullBackup()`.

Backup and restore works perfectly fine if `backupEnable` (see code below) is `true` and `super` is called. However, if `backupEnable` is `false`, the app will be in a strange state after the regular backup run has been performed by the OS or 
`adb shell bmgr fullbackup com.example.app` has been called

**All broadcast receivers defined in `AndroidMainfest.xml` will stop working.** As a consequence, GCM messages will no longer go through.

How can I restore the normal state of the app and especially the broadcast receivers in my custom implementation of `onFullBackup()`? Or is there a better way to let the user enable or disable Android Auto Backup from the app?

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgent {
    @Override
    public void onFullBackup(FullBackupDataOutput data) throws IOException {
        if (backupEnable) {
            super.onFullBackup(data);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Full Backup disabled");
        }
    }
}
```